# How to convert string to camelcase in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert string to camelCase using first some letter(user). Example: useracting, here after user from the string next letter it should be like caps(userActing). How to do it in javascript.

```
var s = "useracting";

var newval = s.replace(/-./g, x=>x[1].toUpperCase());

alert(newval);//userActing
```

newval output should be like userActing

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ylpazx?file=index.js

Comment: How would it be expected to detect word boundaries? For example, if the input was "theredart," there is no way to know if it should be capitalized as "thereDart" or "theRedArt," even if you could identify words.

Comment: If your input string can have word boundaries, such as "user acting" or "user-acting", you can use a generic and therefore more robust [conversion](https://quickref.me/convert-a-string-to-camel-case.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the callback function like the following way:

```js
var s = "useracting";

var newval = s.replace(/user([a-z])/g, (match, group1) => 'user' + group1.toUpperCase());

console.log(newval); //userActing
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution.

```js
function replacer(match,p1,offset){
    return match.toUpperCase();
}
let s = "useracting";
let r=s.replace(/(?<=user)\w{1}/,replacer);
console.log(r)
```